# Error message every time I try to install applications

Tags: raspbian, python

```
Error processing line 1 of /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk2-2.0-pysupport-compat.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 162, in addpackage
      if not dircase in known_paths and os.path.exists(dir):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 18, in exists
      os.stat(path)
  TypeError: must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str

Remainder of file ignored
database /var/lib/apt/listchanges.db failed to load.
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (strict.pm did not return a true value at (eval 1) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 2.
) -- aborting
dpkg: error: fgets gave an empty string from `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to install .deb files. You probably are missing dependencies.

See these answers to try and automatically find missing dependencies.

[Ans1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58202/how-to-automatically-fetch-missing-dependencies-when-installing-software-from-d/58207)
[Ans2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433248/check-dependencies-and-generate-download-script-before-installing-by-dpkg)
[Ans3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80655/how-can-i-check-dependency-list-for-a-deb-package)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will check out your suggestions.  Hope to solve this problem because my original intention was not to learn raspbian but to setup a programming environment for the Sunfounder kit.

Comment: May be [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md) is what you are looking for.  I really wanted to use Debian so I installed Rasbian Jessie, but it is too buggy. You might be better of using the [Lubuntu version for Raspberry](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/blog/ubuntu-pi-flavours-for-raspberry-pi-3/)